# How do I install gym-minigrid on Anaconda 3 (and from git in general)?

Tags: git, anaconda, openai-gym

The only directions online are:

```
git clone https://github.com/maximecb/gym-minigrid.git 

cd gym-minigrid

pip3 install -e .
```

I tried installing git to an Anaconda kernel but it is not possible. I installed git on my windows 7 environment but I cannot access it with !git.  Also !pip3 is not working from the Anaconda terminal.

If someone can help please also tell me how to cancel the update of the dependencies because I heard it will ruin everything installed and I will need to remake a fresh installation (I have already done 1).

Comment: In the Anaconda terminal, you should type the command names without `!` before them. Have you tried that?

Comment: dear @alexis thank you a lot for your help. I tried to do the git clone command but i get this error: 
>git clone https://github.com/maximecb/gym-minigrid.git
  File "<ipython-input-4-182aa85a091f>", line 1
    git clone https://github.com/maximecb/gym-minigrid.git
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: do you mean the pip command?

Comment: I meant Anaconda terminal (which will give you an OS prompt), not the Python command line. Look for it. Maybe look for a tutorial on how to use the Anaconda environment. All of these commands must be typed at an operating system (shell) prompt.

Comment: I am executing everything in Jupyter QtConsolle. Isn't that correct?

Comment: I found the anaconda prompt, cloned the git repository of minigrid in my directory but still cannot install it

Comment: With what? "Cannot install it" is not a problem anyone can help you with!